# Единая шифровка/расшифровка в php и js

Tags: php, javascript

Дело в том что одна платёжная система принимает только латиницу( А есть потребность передать в мой обработчик русское слово. Есть ли какая-нибудь функция которая шифрует и расшифровывает одинаково как в php, так и в js. Например, если бы в js существовала бы функция перевода в 64-ричную систему счисления, как в php, то я бы при передачи с помощью js обработал бы слово, а в php-обработчике обратно в нормальный вид привёл. Так то на js писали любители base64_encode/base64_decode, но иногда не совпадает с php шифровкой почему-то. И тут же вопросик будет может у кого-то есть функция по преобразованию в транслит и обратно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался либо `base64`, либо [**`uuencode`.**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUE)

---

Насчет `base64` - это кодирование обратимо и однозначно, что говорит о том, что, вероятнее всего, где-то в вашем коде была ошибка. В качестве альтернативной реализации на `javascript` можете попробовать [**вот эту.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript#246813)

По поводу `uuencode` - в `php` это реализуется с помощью `convert_uuencode`, на `javascript` есть [**порт**](http://phpjs.org/functions/convert_uuencode:769) этой самой функции.

Comment: спасибо, а по транслиту ничего не скажите?

Comment: @mctrane Гугл обычно творит чудеса :) Можете воспользоваться любым из вариантов, описанных [**здесь.**][1]

[1]: http://forum.dklab.ru/js/other/Translit.html